# pytube error while downloading video: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, pytube

I am making a simple youtube video downloader.It download videos without any errors but when i try to download this "[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ6W3ryNVNE&list=PLqzeul28y04UGw8RHAN37Gjh0ZLmg3-qe)" it gives error.I have downloaded this video many times before without any errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Python\jarvis\test1.py", line 15, in <module>
    d = yt.streams.filter(res = "240p").first()
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 311, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 214, in fmt_streams
    if "adaptive_fmts" in self.player_config_args:
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in player_config_args
    self._player_config_args = self.vid_info
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 281, in vid_info 
    return dict(parse_qsl(self.vid_info_raw))
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 109, in vid_info_raw
    self._vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 53, in get        
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Roshaan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default      
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I don't understand why this happens.I saw same questions asked by others and updated pytube which accepted solution by others but that didn't worked for me.This is the my code

```
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ6W3ryNVNE&list=PLqzeul28y04UGw8RHAN37Gjh0ZLmg3-qe")
d = yt.streams.filter(res = "240p").first()
d.download()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is a reoccurring issue with the `pytube` package. It seems to be fixed after each update but then it goes back to this issue. If you have ran `pip install --upgrade pytube` and the problem is still there then you'll have to wait for the next update.

While waiting, I'd suggest you using an alternative to `pytube`... `youtube_dl` you might want to check this out as it is more reliable. Official [website](https://youtube-dl.org/), [installation](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/).

Comment: i upgraded from pytube 10.9.2 to 10.9.3 but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Then you might want to use `youtube_dl` as an alternative until the next update for `pytube`.

Comment: No problem bro. :-)